# Thymeleaf looping over list of objects with list of objects attribute problem

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, render

I'm working in Spring Boot and I have a problem rendering with Thymeleaf a table with different lines. First must be a String, and the subsequent lines must be the data saved in a list of objects.

situation of the problem:

I have a list of objects, this object has two attributes, one is a list of Strings, and the other one is a list of different objects. I don't know how to render in Thymeleaf in a table the first attribute of a string list in a line, and on the next lines of the table render the second list of attribute object.

details of the object:

```java
public class objetosDeServiciosAD {

    private String Servicio;
    private LinkedList<usuarioAD> listaUsuariosAD;

    public String getServicio() {
        return Servicio;
    }
    public void setServicio(String servicio) {
        Servicio = servicio;
    }
    public LinkedList<usuarioAD> getListaUsuariosAD() {
        return listaUsuariosAD;
    }
    public void setListaUsuariosAD(LinkedList<usuarioAD> listaUsuariosAD) {
        this.listaUsuariosAD = listaUsuariosAD;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "objetosDeServiciosAD [Servicio=" + Servicio + ", listaUsuariosAD=" + listaUsuariosAD + "]";
    }
        
}
```

objetos_Servicios is a list of objects with two atributes, one is servicio
this object has a second attibute which is a list of objects, this is listaUsuariosAD.

This is my code in Thymeleaf:

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Usuario</th>
            <th scope="col">Teléfono</th>
            <th scope="col">mail</th>
            <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="servicio : ${objetos_Servicios}">
            <td th:text="${servicio.servicio}"></td>            
        <tr th:each=" listaeusuario : ${servicio.listaUsuariosAD}">
            <tr th:each ="usuarios : ${listaeusuario}">
                <td th:text = "${usuarios.usuario}"></td>
                <td th:text = "${usuarios.telefono}"></td>
                <td th:text = "${usuarios.mail}"></td>
                <td th:text = "${usuarios.descripion}"></td>
                  
            </tr>
        </tr>                            
    </tbody> 
      
</table>
```

Comment: the error is in : Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as each: " listaeusuario : {servicio.listaUsuariosAD}" (template: "listusuariosAD" - line 46, col 20)

Comment: The first thing I think you need to fix is the structure of the HTML in your Thymeleaf template. Some notes: (1) You have `<tr>` elements nested inside `<tr>` elements. (2) You have a body row which does not contain 4 columns (it does not match the header) and which does not use colspans. (3) You have 3 opening `<tr>` elements but only 2 closing `<tr>` elements.

Comment: I recommend you first build a static HTML table (no Thymeleaf) which shows the structure of the output you want Thymeleaf to generate. Then you can look at how to create that structure using Thymeleaf. You can update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The code will look something like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Usuario</th>
      <th scope="col">Teléfono</th>
      <th scope="col">mail</th>
      <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <th:block th:each="servicio : ${objetos_Servicios}">
      <tr>
        <td th:text="${servicio.servicio}" />
      </tr>          
      
      <tr th:each = "lista : ${servicio.getListaUsuariosAD()}">
        <td th:text="${lista.usuario}"></td>
        <td th:text="${lista.telefono}"></td>
        <td th:text="${lista.mail}"></td>
        <td th:text="${lista.Descripcion}"></td>
      </tr>
    </th:block>
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

You can use a `th:block` tag to loop over a larger block of code (that contains the header `<tr />` and the rows `<tr />`).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing the naming standards you are using, so that all your class names begin with an upper-case letter - for example: `ObjetosDeServiciosAD` instead of `objetosDeServiciosAD`. This is standard in Java - and not doing this can be confusing for other people who read your code.

So, your class becomes:

```java
import java.util.List;

public class ObjetosDeServiciosAD {

    private String servicio;
    private List<UsuarioAD> listaUsuariosAD;

    public String getServicio() {
        return servicio;
    }

    public void setServicio(String servicio) {
        this.servicio = servicio;
    }

    public List<UsuarioAD> getListaUsuariosAD() {
        return listaUsuariosAD;
    }

    public void setListaUsuariosAD(List<UsuarioAD> listaUsuariosAD) {
        this.listaUsuariosAD = listaUsuariosAD;
    }

}
```

I also replaced `LinkedList` with `List`, since you do not appear to need a linked list here (if you actually do, you can revert that change).

Then, for your Thymeleaf template, you can use Thymeleaf's [`<th:block>`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#synthetic-thblock-tag) tag to structure your iteration loops:

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Usuario</th>
            <th scope="col">Teléfono</th>
            <th scope="col">mail</th>
            <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <th:block th:each="servicio : ${objetos_Servicios}">
            <tr>
                <td th:text="${servicio.servicio}" />
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>          

            <tr th:each = "lista : ${servicio.listaUsuariosAD}">
                <td th:text="${lista.usuario}"></td>
                <td th:text="${lista.telefono}"></td>
                <td th:text="${lista.mail}"></td>
                <td th:text="${lista.descripcion}"></td>
            </tr>
        </th:block>
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

In the above code, I also replaced `${servicio.getListaUsuariosAD()}` with the simpler `${servicio.listaUsuariosAD}`, since you do not need to explicitly call the method, here.

I also added three empty `<td></td>` cells to ensure each row is complete, for the row displaying the `servicio` text.

Comment: perfect, your recommendation finally worked for me code, I want to thank you for your profesionality, your code helped me a lot, again, thank you very much for your help.